# Typescript/React `<span>Text</span>`only writes out the text and not element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, string-interpolation, preact

I have this quite simple function that splits a string and puts in a styles span in the middle as i want some styled text there it looks like this

```
splitAndApplyStyledContent(content: string, textType: string, separator: string) {
  const splittedContent = content.split(separator);

  switch (textType) {
    case 'Info':
      return [
        splittedContent[0],
        `<span className="styled-text">${this.getString(Name)}</span>`,
        splittedContent[1],
      ];
    default:
      return content;
  }
}
```

The problem here is that when i call it in my tsx file like

```
{ props.myStringManager.splitAndApplyStyledContent(props.myStringManager.getString(infoContent), "Info" , '{X}')}
```

it will also write out the `<span className="styled-text"> </span>` part instead of making it into an element and applying the style to it

To clarify this function is inside a class that looks like `export default class LocalizationsManager`so not a component or anything like it it is also an .ts file and no .tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a valid JSX, not an array:

```
...
return (
  <>
    {splittedContent[0]}
    <span className='styled-text'>{this.getString(Name)}</span>
    {splittedContent[1]}
  </>
)
...
```

Comment: it wont allow me to write like that to edit this is a function in a class that looks like export default class LocalizationsManager {

Comment: If it is a class component, put it inside the render function: `render() {return<div>/div>;}`

Comment: You clearly want to return JSX in your function. Consider refactoring your code